# How to reset Animation transformation after the activity is hidden in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-animation, transformation

I have a listview in android where after clicking an item, I start an animation with transformation that scales the listitem to fill the screen. At the end of this transformation I reset the size of the list item so that the view is restored to its original layout when a user gets back to the listview. After the animation is done, a new activity is started.

My problem is that the resizing of the list item back to it's original shape, is done before the activity is hidden.

```
Animation a = new Animation()
{

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        if(interpolatedTime == 1)
        {   
            v.getLayoutParams().height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.pdft_list_item_height);
         }
         else
         {
             //Resizing of list view
         }
    }
}
```

Since the list item has a background image that matches the image on the next screen, I want to give the illusion that the background image hasn't changed. At the moment the background of the list item resizes back to its original shape just before the activity becomes invisible. I want the resizing back to happen after the acitivity has gone invisible.

Looking at the activity lifecycle, I would implement this in the activity `onPause()` or `onEnd()`, but at that point the view has gone out of scope.

Comment: instead of checking if(interpolatedTime == 1) try to implement animation listener in your custom animation class

Comment: I have an animation listener in my activity. But I don't have access to the View in the onAnimationEnd(). And to my knowledge, this is also called while the activity is visible. Or what do you suggest that I could do in this function?

Comment: so after clicking the item you start a new Activity, right?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my question to reflect this more clearly.